# running an sql file in mac terminal

Tags: mysql, database, macos, terminal

I'm stuck trying to run a mysql statement from a file - seems if I'm outside the cd usr/local/mysql/bin directory - I get a mysql command not found error, and if I'm inside it, it can't find the path to the mysql file. The mysql file is currently in my user folder. I'm supposed to be running a command like:

```
mysql -u user -phpuser password < path/to/file.sql
```

Anybody know how to get this working?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u user -phpuser password < path/to/file.sql` work?

Comment: It might - but I don't know how to specify that path - what is it relative to? Where do I need to be in the shell to execute that command? I've tried a bunch of combinations and get either the mysql not found error or file not found error.

Comment: `path/to/file` is relative to your current location.

Comment: https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `mysql` is in `/usr/local/mysql/bin` rather than `/usr/local/bin` then update your `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

In your question, you have a dash in front of the username, try:

```
mysql --user=phpuser --password=password < /path/to/file.sql
```